# Inject HTML markup into web forms button control text property

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I wonder if it is possible to make something like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnContinueShopping" OnClick="btnContinueShopping_Click" runat="server" Text="<i>italic text</i>Nastavi sa kupovinom" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
```

to render properly. Any clue whether is it feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your HTML from the Text property and put inside the asp:Button tag, like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnContinueShopping" OnClick="btnContinueShopping_Click" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary"><i>italic text</i>Nastavi sa kupovinom</asp:Button>
```

**Updated:**

Sorry, I was mistaken, the Button tag does not support this. But you can use a LinkButton instead, and as you are using Bootstrap, it will look and function the same.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnContinueShopping" OnClick="btnContinueShopping_Click" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary"><i>italic text</i>Nastavi sa kupovinom</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: tnx, but it won't work.  I am getting Literal content ('<i>italic text</i>Nastavi sa kupovinom') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken, the Button tag does not support this. But you can use a LinkButton instead, and as you are using Bootstrap, it will look and function the same. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you John it works, I was bit suspicious at the beginning cause I have ValidationGroup attribute on it - but everything works same way as web forms button control.